# Python scrips failing and dropping 0 CPU usage

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

My overall goal of the scripts is to do a efficient ping of a /8 network. To do this I am running 32 scripts at the same time to scan a /13 each.

the basic of the script is

```
import ipaddress
import time
import fileinput
import pingpack
set = 0
mainset =0
while mainset < 8:
    while set < 256:
        net_addr = ("10.{}.{}.0/24".format(mainset,set))
        ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(net_addr)
        all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())
        f_out_file=('{}_Ping.txt'.format(mainset))
    for i in range(len(all_hosts)):
        output = pingpack.ping("{}".format(all_hosts[i]))
        if output != None:
            with open(f_out_file,'a',newline="\n") as file:
                file.write("{}, Y\r\n".format(all_hosts[i]))

    print ("{}".format("Subnet Complete"))
    set = set + 1
set=0
```

The script it self works and runs and gives me a good output when ran by it self. The issue i am running into is when i get 32 of these running for each subnet they run for about 8 set loops before the python process locks up and stops writing.

The script I am using to start the 32 is as follows

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time
i = 0
count=0
while i < 32:
    process = Popen(['ping{}.py'.format(i),"{}".format(count)], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    print(count)
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    count=count+8
    time.sleep(1)
```

In this case; Yes; I do have 32 duplicate scrips each with a 2 lines changed for the different /13 subents. It may be as effect as some; but it gets them started and running.

How would I go about finding the reason for the stop for these scripts?

Side note: Yes I know I can do this with something like NMAP or Angry IP Scanner; but they both take 90+ hours to scan a entire /8; I am trying to shorten this down to something that can be ran in a more reasonable timeframe.

Comment: I doubt you'll beat nmap's performance - they have a multithreaded/parallelism mode to help throughput: https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack The problem i have ran into namp is that i does a double scan (discovery and then port scan) on east host; on top of that if the process breaks halfway thu i lose all data; where in python i can constantly write to the file and no loss of data.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am running windows 7 and sadly do not have access to a linux distro on the network; I figure a simple bash script could turn this out quicker and cleaner then python, but that is not a option.

Comment: @Talauna `nmap -sn` is a ping only scan. It completed my /24 in 3.9 seconds

Comment: @Talauna, yep, was going to suggest doing it using linux, you can also access nmap though python so writing to the file is completely possible. It can all be done  asynchronously so it will also be fast

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack to expand on the command and using parallelism;  nmap -sn --min-parallelism 100 -T5 -oN c:/dump/nmapscan.txt 10.0.0.0/8 is looking to be a 48 hour ping span. from what I am seeing even some of the host discovery can not be pushed faster. This is still quicker then the python script (running at 32 processes vs namp) and still quicker then angry ip scanner. If i could get the python scrip to run 64 or 128 in parallel then python could be quicker.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am still trying to get the hang of multiprocessing in python with map; not there yet but once i get that going the script can be done quickly (if the computer can keep up)

Comment: @Talauna, `nmap.PortScannerAsync`

Comment: @Talauna: unrelated: a bad workman blames his tools (python might not be the best tool for the job here but you can't make this claim given the (poor) quality of your code that I see). [ZMap](https://zmap.io/) is capable of performing a complete scan of the IPv4 address space in under 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that `set` is never set back to zero when you move on to the next mainset.  Your second problem is that `mainset` never increments.  Rather than a pair of obscure while-loops, why not:

```
for mainset in xrange(8):
    for set in xrange(256):
```

Also, `in range(len(all_hosts))` is a code smell (and it turns out that you never use `i` except to write `all_hosts[i]`).  Why not:

```
        for host in all_hosts:
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this; I was able to get the range to work with     for mainset in range(0,8,1) and  for set in range(0,255,1): as xrange no longer exists in 3.x python

Comment: Wanted to add this this; been running this for about 1 hour and the script has not stopped. Looks like it was just fubaring the loop. Thank you again.

Comment: If you are using Python 3, just use `range(8)` .  `range(x)` is equivalent to `range(0,x,1)`.